# How to check whether hacker modified or altered table or added column to database

Tags: mysql, database, wordpress, function

I need to check whether hacker modified or altered table or added column to MySQL database in PHPMyAdmin or if he changed a Wordpress file on server so he can continue hacking my site for nefarious purposes.

I noticed that website hits dropped by more than 2/3 since July 19th and wondered what happened. This pic shows I had 1800 visits but the chart shows only 600 visits at http://tinypic.com/r/1zw0nxv/8 
Immediately I felt that my site got hacked and someone was stealing my traffic. 
So I said, "What plugins or themes" did you install on the 18? 
I had installed a purchased plugin on the 18th.

I noticed that a WP plugin called SQL Executioner was installed without my permission a few days ago. Knowing that I had installed a 
plugin on the 18th or 19th I figured that the SQL Executioner plugin was packaged with it or the code to install it was placed in plugin that I uploaded to WP admin dashboard. I have no experience with SQL commands but 
I've read on Wordfence and other sites that hackers can use your site to launch attacks, load ads to their offers, or steal traffic using plugins and themes. 
I think SQL Executioner gave the hacker access to MySQL database in PHPMyAdmin so they can steal my traffic.

I checked out SQL Executioner at https://github.com/justincwatt/wp-sql-executioner/blob/master/sql-executioner.php and you can alter and modify tables or add columns.

FYI: I deleted the plugin I installed on the 18th and removed all 3 of its tables in PHPMyAdmin MySQL and 2 rows in wp_options table. 
I found no (obvious) rows or tables for SQL Executioner in MYSQL.

My stats are still low so the hacker still has access to my site (even after I changed my login) because he's got database access. 
I'd like someone to help me find out what tables or columns were modified, altered or added to my database on the 18th or 19th. 
In other words, I'd like to know what commands were executed on my database because I never execute commands, do operations, triggers, etc at all. Or if the hacker stored the malware code in a Wordpress file on the server via the database hacking.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Stealing your traffic? A badguy could only do this by hijacking your DNS or by doing redirects from your site. The DNS attack would drop your traffic to zero. The redirect attack wouldn't affect your hits much. It's extremely unlikely that a reputable commercial plugin vendor would bundle something like SQL Executioner without telling you the customer.

Comment: Presumably you have seen what the WordPress.org people recommend on this topic. If not, that's where to start.  https://codex.wordpress.org/FAQ_My_site_was_hacked

Answer (score 0):

The first and foremost method simply is to implement Auditing in MYSQL side.   Now if you're a database expert , that's probably the easiest way to track and then run regular audit reports for anomalies .   For e.g reports such as if the number of columns increased, or certain create table or alter table has issued is a good start.   Also good to see which modules the code is coming from.
During such audits, you can also run parallel session information to correlate from which application it's originating to confirm your application modules on the application servers.

The same can be done by running queries from your front-end to the audit log/history tables and produce the needed results.
If you're even too paranoid, you can implement audit with select queries related to your tables which has the most secure information and see where those queries are coming from.   You can have a report/query that sends periodic information if those queries are coming from a resource or location that's not your application server.   Then you catch the culprit.   These audit reports/queries can be scheduled jobs that run periodically or they can run based on triggers if you're still more paranoid :-)

NOTE:  This is a reactive solution.   If your network security , sql code and front-end code and all done through good security standards , you'll have less chance of facing such situations.    It's good to hire an expert to provide such indepth analysis of security for your systems and datbases and make sure to begin with all unnecessary ports, services, communications etc., are all blocked and secured.   So you can deal with little or no security issues.